# How to trace SQL dependencies in one code block

Tags: sql, dependencies

I have a stored procedure for 2000 lines, it has about 20 temporary tables, 170 indicators (columns) a lot of different transformations, and because of this it is difficult to trace what table or column comes from, except of doing it manually in notepad.
Is there any other options to trace the dependencies inside one block of sql code (stored procedure) ?

and I mean not dependencies between database objects, but inside one code block.

Comment: Someone asked a very similar question just a few days ago. See if you can find it.